# Assignment operator does not work

Tags: c#

When I debug the code, I see there is a numeric value but it does not update `Model.Weight`.

```
private Person Model { get; set; }

public void Init(string pId)
{
```

// just get the data from the local database, it is not empty
      Model = _personService.GetPerson(pId);
    }

```
public decimal Weight
{
   get { return Model.Weight; }
   set
   {
     //there is a numeric value here, but Model.Weight does not get updated.
     Model.Weight = value;
   }
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person
{
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `Weight` a static variable of `Model`?

Comment: Show a) the definition of Weight and b) why you think it does not get updated.

Comment: It is not static.         `public decimal Weight { get; set; }`

Comment: where did you call or assign Weight?

Comment: Can you provide a slightly more complete, runnable code example so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: I have added `Person` class.

Comment: is it Console or MVC or ASP.Net? where are executing? where are you calling Weight? where are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: it is mvvmcross, I am getting `Weight` from the `EditText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment works fine:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Init("abc");
        var person = foo.Model;
        foo.Weight = 123.45M;
        Console.WriteLine(person.Weight); // 123.45
    }
    private Person Model { get; set; }

    public void Init(string pId)
    {
        Model = _personService.GetPerson(pId);
    }

    public decimal Weight
    {
        get { return Model.Weight; }
        set { Model.Weight = value; }
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
static class _personService // yes I know this isn't representative of your setup
{
    internal static Person GetPerson(string pId)
    {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, What is difference from my code, I have not seen any difference.

Comment: There isn't any difference. That's the point. The assignment works fine. The problem lies in code that you have not presented.

Comment: @hotspring for us to find your error, we're going to need a runnable example. Try to create one. I suspect you'll find the problem yourself in doing it.